# Is using temporary placeholders for CSV special characters a bad practice?

Tags: java, string, csv

I'm working with a lot of CSV files with many different formats and usually written by hand by common users, so there are a lot of `;` `,` `\n` and `\t` and such inside the fields, this kind of characters usually cause trouble when parsing the data or generating new CSV files, and i usually remove such characters beforehand, but today i found the following code in an old program :

It reads data from a `resultSet` and concatenates each value into a `String` to form a row, and to deal with separators (we usually use `;`), this code first used a temporary flag like `#TempSeparator#` to divide each field, then, when the row is complete, applies a `replaceAll(";","")` to remove the fake separators, and after that, a `replaceAll("#TempSeparator#", ";")` to form a valid row

I actually thought that was a clever way to avoid unnecessary calls for each field, and doing the replacements only to the full line, but I don't think its the best or even optimal way to do so.

Is this really a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not *very* bad, but also not the best approach.

Use standard libraries wherever possible. [Here is a list](https://stackabuse.com/libraries-for-reading-and-writing-csvs-in-java/) of fine libraries, of which SuperCSV is particularly strong in supporting CSV variants. These libraries follow best practices: Special characters are escaped when used inside a field, or the field is wrapped (usually with quotes).

If the CSV is already malformed so that special characters appear inside the fields without proper escaping or wrapping, then you have a data-cleaning problem on your hands, to be solved in some other way. Replacing the character with your temporary placeholder will not fix that, as the placeholder will likewise appear both inside the fields and between them.

Answer (score 1):

This approach doesn't sound very elegant to me. You describe:

1. Per input field, concatenate it onto a single string using `#TempSeparator#`
2. Eliminate all `;` from the resulting string
3. Replace all occurrences of `#TempSeparator#` with `;`

That's 3 steps. How about instead:

1. Per input field, strip out all `;`
2. Then, concatenate it onto a single string using `;`

It's a step less. Therefore, better.

Some example code to show off why this is simpler:

stream-style:

```
collection.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("#TempSeparator#"))
    .replace(";", "").replace("#TempSeparator#", ";");
```

vs.

```
collection.stream().map(x -> x.replace(";", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is overdesigned, an unnecessary artifact.

At least use a constant char:

```
private static final char TEMP_SEPARATOR = '\u001f';
```

- Often the tab does not occur in text `\t` and it is an ideal separator.
- Otherwise a control character would do: Unit Separator `\u001f`. Possibly a Unicode one.
- An almost otherwise unusable char is `\u0000`.

The advantage is its efficiency:

```
s = s.replace(';', ',').replace('\u0000', ';');
```

The best solution still being replacing the separator of the cell value itself.
As probably has to be done for newlines.

Concerning the final separator: IMHO tab is a better choice than semicolon, because replacing tabs with spaces does change the text only w.r.t. whitespace. That is: no requirement can arise. Like the room number must be floor ";" number.